# why negative value in rotateX in css doesnt change the direction of rotation

Tags: css, transform

If you put in css `transform: rotateY(-30deg)` vs `transform: rotateY(30deg)`. You will have two different results, the results you would expect. Rotate in one direction or the other. Same with Z axis.

But with X axis it doesnt seem to be the case. I want top side to come in front while bottom side to go back when rotating over X axis.

Check out the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/x5Qgx/3/

Is it bug in css?

I know I could give it value like 330 or something but that rotates it two times and messes up the animation I want. If it wasn't for the animation I'd have used that.

Sooo frustrating.

It works for Y, Z but why not for X?

Comment: The rotateX doesn't seem to have any effect. Where can one find the documentation of these commands?

Comment: it does have effect in chrome but only half that is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is showing the orthographic projection.

You need to define the perspective to the parent element:

```
-webkit-perspective: 500px;
-moz-perspective: 500px;
-o-perspective: 500px;
perspective: 500px;
```

More info at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective

Comment: Try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kiqyn

If it still looks weird, maybe try setting `perspective-origin` on the parent to be right in the center of your image.

Comment: i don't know what i was doing wrong as i was using perspective but now it works..lol..oh also perspective property can be on the rotated element itself...thanks http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqbwk

Comment: I didn't know you could add perspective to the element itself :O I've learned something :D

Comment: now it only works if you have perspective on child in chrome weird